# Return parent if hits child/granchild

Tags: elasticsearch

I have relation:

```
            "relation_type" => [
                "type" => "join",
                "eager_global_ordinals" => true,
                "relations" => [
                    "parent" => "child",
                    "child" => "grandchild",
                ],
            ],
```

How can I receive "parent" if I hit "child" or "grandchild"?

```
                "relation_type": {
                    "name": "grandchild",
                    "parent": 1
                },
```

Comment: Could you please provide some relevant snippets of your document, mapping, query and desired output? It's hard to understand unfortunately what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For parent/child-ish query for ES, the logic is that if you want to return parent, you search for parent, but add a has_child component to your query.

In your example, since you would consider two type of relations, I think you will need to add a OR query to deal with the fact that either the hit is a child or a grandchild, with grandchild itself , something like:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "child",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "child",
            "query": {
              "has_child": {
                "type": "grandchild",
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Change `"match_all": {}` to whatever other query you would like

Do be noted that I suggest you organize your datastructure in a way that you don't have to create queries like that. Even a single join in ES can be fairly expensive.